# How to start FragmentActivity from onNavigationItemSelected method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I used following segment to replace `FrameLayout` with `Fragment` inside `onNavigationItemSelected` method,

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     Fragment fragment;

     if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
         fragment = new MyFragment();
         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
         ft.commit();
     }
     else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

     }
     else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

     }
     else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

     } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

     } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

     }
}
```

I wanted to replace `FrameLayout` with `FragmentActivity`, then I did

```
FragmentActivity fragmentAc;

 if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
     fragmentAc= new MyFragmentActivity();
     FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragmentAc);
     ft.commit();
 }
```

but getting `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', required: 'android.app.Fragment'` on line `ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragmentAc);`

What should I change now, Help me

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJhbO634TWAhWEgI8KHWK0DFwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2013%2F11%2Fandroid-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer%2F&usg=AFQjCNH6oem0YHOSVrafShcOfa3-8wVmzw

Comment: @GowthamanM I wanted to open `FragmentActivity` not `Fragment` so please read question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass `FragmentActivity` where it requires `Fragment`, that's what error says.

If you want to open another activity rather than replacing fragment, you have to call `startActivity(...)`

replace:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
     fragmentAc= new MyFragmentActivity();
     FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragmentAc);
     ft.commit();
 }
```

with:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MyFragmentActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: I want to replace `FrameLayout` with `MyFragmentActivity`

Comment: that's not possible you can't open an activity within another activity. you will have to add one more in back stack and so there is only possible way to do it by using `startActivity`

Comment: For clarification/understanding read Fragment & Activity documentation from Android.